# Unsure how to assemble Shakespeare SSB antenna; not working

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, vhf

Have 23 foot [Shakespeare](http://shakespeare-ce.com/marine/) SSB antenna.  Can not connect  through the side feed termination band? Antenna not working?  What is the band supposed to look like? Is the termination band supposed to be smooth on inside of band? How does the termination band connect to the antenna pole? Is there supposed to be a metal bead on the inside of the band??  I am NOT referring to where my lead connects to the band, as show in company diagram, how does the band connect to the antenna pole? Have sent emails to Shakespeare tech support. They do not answer. Can not find diagram or picture of **actual** side feed termination band.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Amateur Radio Stack Exchange. I think you have a better chance to get an answer if you restructure your question and maybe post a clear picture of the problem you have.

Comment: needs a photo at least, and a link to the _specific_ antenna you are asking about.